# D3 graph with slider, change color of nodes and add labels

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I have a D3 script that creates a graph that has a slider on the side. This slider will only display link nodes that have a degree indicated by the slider. All other nodes will be disconnected and off to the side.

Currently, this code displays them in the same color and has no node labels. I would like the ability to make the nodes on the outside a different color (i.e. gray) to distinguish better from the ones that are disconnected.

I would also like to include labels for these nodes. I would like the labels to be inside the nodes

Any assistance on either of these two issues would be welcome!

My script below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slider Graph</title>
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

.axis {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.axis .domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.axis .halo {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.slider .handle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
  stroke-width: 1.25px;
  cursor: grab;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([250, 80])
    .clamp(true);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .y(x)
    .extent([0, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var links_g = svg.append("g");

var nodes_g = svg.append("g");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20)  + ",0)")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return d; })
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(12))
  .select(".domain")
  .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
    .attr("class", "halo");

var slider = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slider")
    .call(brush);

slider.selectAll(".extent,.resize")
    .remove();

var handle = slider.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20) + ",0)")
    .attr("r", 5);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 15)
    .attr("y", 60)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .text("degree threshold")

d3.json("test4.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  graph.links.forEach(function(d,i){ d.i = i; });
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(d,i){ d.i = i; });

  function brushed() {
    var value = brush.extent()[0];

    if (d3.event.sourceEvent) {
      value = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1]);
      brush.extent([value, value]);
    }
    handle.attr("cy", x(value));
    var threshold = value;
    console.log(graph.nodes);
    var thresholded_nodes = graph.nodes.filter(function(d){ return (d.degree > threshold);});
    var thresholded_links = graph.links.filter(function(d){ return (d.min_degree > threshold);});
    console.log(thresholded_nodes);

    force
        .links(thresholded_links);

    var link = links_g.selectAll(".link")
        .data(thresholded_links, function(d){ return d.i; });

    link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    link.exit().remove();


    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });

    force.start();

  }

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes);

  var node = nodes_g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      // .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  brush.on("brush", brushed);

  slider
    .call(brush.extent([5, 5]))
    .call(brush.event);

});

</script>
```

[download test data here](https://baylor.box.com/shared/static/qoghiqasp5gv8c5idupczg191bxelucf.json)